# WPF rotate an loading image for gif effect

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a static loader image in wpf, I can easily use it as a loading gif by using WPFAnimatedGIF nuget package, but it seems like an overkill.

There is only one scenario in my application where I want to display a busy indicator.

There is nothing to trigger, it is a hidden object in my window and upon certain condition it becomes visible. Thus it should always rotate and appear like a normal animated loading gif.

What I have tried so far

```
 <Image RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Width="44" Height="44" Source="BusyIndicator.gif">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45" />                
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

Image that I am using is

[image]

Comment: You could use a never ending animation, but it has it's [drawback](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49853/Better-WPF-Circular-Progress-Bar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Style animates the Angle of a RotateTransform in 30 degree steps when the Image element is visible.

```
<Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="BusyIndicatorStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="44"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="44"/>
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="BusyIndicator.png"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">

                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="30"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="60"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="90"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="120"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="150"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="180"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="210"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="240"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="270"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="300"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="330"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="360"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

...
<Image Style="{StaticResource BusyIndicatorStyle}" />
```

---

In order to avoid using an animation with many DiscreteDoubleKeyFrames, you may derive from DoubleAnimation and add a `Step` property:

```
public class DoubleAnimationWithSteps : DoubleAnimation
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StepProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Step), typeof(double), typeof(DoubleAnimationWithSteps));

    public double Step
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StepProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override double GetCurrentValueCore(
        double from, double to, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        var value = base.GetCurrentValueCore(from, to, animationClock);

        if (Step > 0d)
        {
            value = Step * Math.Floor(value / Step);
        }

        return value;
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new DoubleAnimationWithSteps();
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <local:DoubleAnimationWithSteps
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
        Duration="0:0:1.2" To="360" Step="30"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question already has an answer, but there is a different approach. Just use ProgressBar and set IsIndeterminate to True:

```
<ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCircularProgressBar}" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="36"/>
```

The style is from [Material Design In XAML Toolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). There is no need to use GIFs as busy indicators, I made the same mistake some time ago