# Moving a triangle using given coordinate

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a project and I want to animate a rectangle to move a certain amount of coordinate that i have set earlier.

Ex: My rectangle is at the position (x=0,y=0). I want with a click of a button to make it move at position (x=150, y=230) in interval of 100 milliseconds. So with one click, it would go to (10,25) at first 100 milliseconds,(20,35) for second 100 milliseconds and so on until the rectangle reach the final position(x=150, y=230)...

I'm working with visual studio and blend on Visual C# wpf.

This is my progress of codes in code-behind file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myRect = (Rectangle)this.FindName("myRect");
    double x = Canvas.GetLeft(myRect);
    double y = Canvas.GetTop(myRect);

    Canvas.SetLeft(myRect,x+10);
    Canvas.SetTop(myRect,y);
```

And this is in XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="move.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:move"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Aqua">
        <Canvas Name="PointCanvas" Width="500" Height="294" Margin="9,0,6,0">
            <Rectangle x:Name="myRect" Fill="#FFF5F4F5" Height="39" Canvas.Left="170" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="89" Width="89"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
    <Button Name="Move" Click="Button_Click">Move</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: So what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Use two DoubleAnimations to animate the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties. As a note, you don't need to call `var myRect = (Rectangle)this.FindName("myRect")`. By setting the `x:Name` attribute in XAML, a member variable `myRect` is generated automatically.

Comment: My current codes do not work as i wish. The rectangle only move +10 in x-axis when i click the 'Move' button once and move another +10 for another click.I thought it should be using the timer but I cannot figure it how.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What's the reason to have these 10 units steps in 100 ms intervals when you could simply use smooth animations? Start reading here: [Animation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview).

Comment: project that i working now is the indoor positioning system..so the rectangle represents us should be move node by node, not directly move to the final location.That is why I want to make it move in 100 ms intervals

Comment: You could perhaps use an animation with discrete steps, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46872229/1136211.