# Animation using discrete values from an array - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, animation

I'm trying to make a rotating image in a C# WPF program.
Is there a way to animate the image using values from an array?

At this time I am using this function to animate `ImageWaiting` :

```
private void StartWaitingAnimation()
{
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation
        (0, 360, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
    RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
    ImageWaiting.RenderTransform = rt;
    ImageWaiting.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
}
```

But this produces a smooth rotation; I would like to obtain something more like a clock, with the steps coming from an array.

Comment: There are discrete animations using key frames (array of frames), see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/key-frame-animations-overview).

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46872229/1136211

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking about, thank you!